# Generic class doesn't call overridden initializer

Tags: swift

```
class Gen<T: A> {
    func create() -> T {
        if T.self is B.Type {
            println("YES")
        }
        return T(id: "cool")
    }
}

class A {
    let id: String

    init(id: String) {
        self.id = id
        println("class A \(id)")
    }
}

class B: A {
    override init(id: String) {
        println("class B \(id)")
        super.init(id: id)
    }
}

let coll = Gen<B>()
let t = coll.create()
```

output is
"YES"
"class A cool"

There is no output from overridden B.init.

Is that a compiler bug? Do I need to do it differently?

Xcode 6.1

Comment: see my answer about this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280176/swift-generics-not-preserving-type/26284281#26284281

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**That looks like a compiler bug**.

If you try:

```
NSStringFromClass(t.dynamicType)
```

it (playground) outputs something like:

> __lldb_expr_781.A

so `t` is of type `A`. More interestingly:

```
let t: B = coll.create()
```

doesn't generate any compilation error, but it's a huge compilation mistake, because if the instance is of type `A`, it cannot be assigned to a variable of type `B` (because `B` is a subclass of `A`, but the opposite is possible thanks to polymorphism).

To prove that: add any property to the `B` class, like:

```
var x = 0
```

if you try accessing it:

```
t.x
```

a runtime error is reported (EXC_BAD_ACCESS).

Also read [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26220610/148357), it's a similar problem (if not the same)

Comment: Yes one of Apply guys said it's a known issue https://devforums.apple.com/thread/251920?tstart=0

Comment: Ok - I suggest you to file a radar

Answer (score 0):

You need to make initializers `required`, then add `let realType = T.self` line to `create()` method and replace `T()` with `realType()`.

```
class Gen<T: A> {
    func create() -> T {
        let realType = T.self
        return realType(id: "cool")
    }
}

class A {
    let id: String

    required init(id: String) {
        self.id = id
        println("class A \(id)")
    }
}

class B: A {
    required init(id: String) {
        println("class B \(id)")
        super.init(id: id)
    }
}

let coll = Gen<B>()
let t = coll.create()
```