# Is it possible to restrict a Swift generic class function return type to the same class or subclass?

Tags: inheritance, swift, polymorphism, generics

I am extending a base class (one which I do not control) in Swift. I want to provide a class function for creating an instance typed to a subclass. A generic function is required. However, an implementation like the one below does not return the expected subclass type.

```
class Calculator {
    func showKind() { println("regular") }
}

class ScientificCalculator: Calculator {
    let model: String = "HP-15C"
    override func showKind() { println("scientific") }
}

extension Calculator {
    class func create<T:Calculator>() -> T {
        let instance = T()
        return instance
    }
}

let sci: ScientificCalculator = ScientificCalculator.create()
sci.showKind()
```

The debugger reports `T` as `ScientificCalculator`, but `sci` is `Calculator` and calling `sci.showKind()` returns "regular".

Is there a way to achieve the desired result using generics, or is it a bug?

Comment: It returns Calculator for me using Playground. Xcode 6.1.1?

Comment: It does for me too (Console app), but shouldn't it return a `ScientificCalculator`.

Comment: The type IS Calculator create<T:Calculator>

Comment: ScientificCalculator: Calculator => ScientificCalculator is Type Calculator

Comment: Is there a reason not to just do `let sci = ScientificCalculator()`.  What are you hoping to gain with `create()` method?

Comment: @vacawama This is just an abstraction of the issue. I don't have control of the base class and want to extend it to provide strongly typed factory capability.

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus, right, but when stepping through the code. T is reported as ScientificCalculator. That's what I expect to be initialized and returned.

Comment: I think the issue is related to a [possible bug](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/233089)

Comment: I thought showKind was supposed to return the String "{model "HP-15C"}" ?

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus, sure, just the overridden function and return the model and not "scientific". Either way that would be the expected behavior, but the method called is the base class' `showKind`.

Comment: So create shall create an instance of any subclass of Calculator? Just to make sure..

Comment: @Alex, yes, this is a contrived example to represent the problem. I don't have control of the base class, but would like to extend it in a way that referencing the class method on a subclass will create a typed instance of that subclass. Implementing the method on each subclass is not desirable and, I don't think, should be required since the type can be inferred from the generic method.

Comment: In my answer you don`t have to extend the subclasses. Only requirement will be the init. But well in cases that you would need a factory method this will most likely exist. Atleast i can't think of a case where a factory method would be needed and no usable inits would be present.

Comment: @Alex, only problem is I don't control the base class and `init` on the base is not required so the return type is the base class and not the subclass as it should be.

Answer (score 8):

Ok, from the [developer forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1064957#1064957), if you have control of the base class, you might be able to implement the following work around.

```
class Calculator {
    func showKind() { println("regular") }
    required init() {}
}

class ScientificCalculator: Calculator {
    let model: String = "HP-15C"
    override func showKind() { println("\(model) - Scientific") }
    required init() {
        super.init()
    }
}

extension Calculator {
    class func create<T:Calculator>() -> T {
        let klass: T.Type = T.self
        return klass()
    }
}

let sci:ScientificCalculator = ScientificCalculator.create()
sci.showKind()
```

Unfortunately if you do not have control of the base class, this approach is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug somewhere - I mean, not in your code :)

This is obviously a generic method:

```
class func create<T:Calculator>() -> T
```

`T` is inferred by the type of the variable the return value is assigned to, which in your case is `ScientificCalculator`.

A more interesting case. Let's modify the `create` function such that the type of `T` is made explicit, regardless of the type of the variable the instance is assigned to:

```
class func create<T:Calculator>(type: T.Type) -> T

let sci: ScientificCalculator = ScientificCalculator.create(ScientificCalculator.self)
```

The result is the same.

A more interesting observation: `sci` is a variable of `ScientificCalculator` type, but it points to an instance of `Calculator`. So this code:

```
sci.model
```

compiles, but generates a runtime exception - because there's no `model` property defined in the base class.

This is clearly a compiler bug: an instance of a superclass is assigned to a variable whose type is one of its subclasses - that should never be possible (although the opposite is possible)

Also read my answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26223323/148357)

Comment: Tried the very same approach with the exact results. I would much rather it be a bug in my code. I'm also trying to work around this using protocols and type aliases, but am not getting very far. Complier warns of ambiguous type aliases. I must be doing something wrong. Any ideas on how to achieve the desired effect using protocols?

Comment: @seanwoodward: You mean that you used the same approach, but got the correct and expected results (the instance is actually of `ScientificCalculator` type)? And no, I have no idea, but probably you won't fix that problem - after all, with protocols you must provide implementations in concrete classes

Comment: I did not get the "correct and expected" results. I got the same as the "less explicit" approach. Very disappointing. Hate to fall back to AnyObject and casting.

Answer (score 1):

Update, i used Calculator as return type which makes no sense. It should be Self, but still a required init has to exist:

```
class Calculator {
    func showKind() { println("regular") }
    required init() {

    }
}

class ScientificCalculator: Calculator {
    let model: String = "HP-15C"
    override func showKind() { println("scientific") }
}

extension Calculator {
    class func create() -> Self {
        return self()
    }
}

var b = ScientificCalculator.create() // HP-15C
b.showKind()
```

---

I addition to Sean Woodward, it will work if Calculators have (required) initializers. Overriding that in a subclass is not needed.

```
class Calculator {
    required init() {

    }
    func showKind() { println("regular") }
}

class ScientificCalculator: Calculator {
    let model: String = "HP-15C"
    override func showKind() { println("scientific") }
}

extension Calculator {
    class func create<T:Calculator>( type:T.Type ) -> T {
        return type() as T
    }
    class func newInstance() -> Calculator {
        return self()
    }
}

var b = ScientificCalculator.newInstance() // HP-15C
b.showKind() // sientific
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't explain why your generic approach isn't working.  I'm just looking for an alternative.

It seems with Swift that they have replaced factory methods with convenience initializers.  You can create a new convenience initializer and add that with an extension to `Calculator`.

```
extension Calculator {
    convenience init(name: String) {
        println(name)
        self.init()
    }
}

let reg = Calculator(name: "Reg")
reg.showKind()  // "regular"

let sci = ScientificCalculator(name: "Sci")
sci.showKind()  // "scientific"
```

Comment: Of course, but I don't have control of all the subclasses either. The generic approach is a definite requirement. Many thanks for your efforts on this issue.

Comment: I didn't do anything to a subclass.  Forgive me, you're asking on a theoretical level and I'm trying to understand what you hope to accomplish on a practical level.  What would you hope to gain by adding a new factory method to the base class that the existing initializer does not provide?

Comment: your point is valid. I am trying to approach the issue similarly. In fact, that very approach may show promise. Part of the problem is the initializer relies on class functions which will be overridden. can't call `self.dynamicType.classFunc()` in my `convenience init`.