# How to create an array of instances of a subclass from a superclass

Tags: swift

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27337286/1658458), I know that I can create an instance of a subclass from a superclass. Yet, I can't figure out how to create an array of the subclass from the superclass.

Drawing on the above example, here's my best shot so far:

```
class Calculator {
    func showKind() { println("regular") }
    required init() {}
}

class ScientificCalculator: Calculator {
    let model: String = "HP-15C"
    override func showKind() { println("\(model) - Scientific") }
    required init() {
        super.init()
    }
}

extension Calculator {
    class func createMultiple<T:Calculator>(num: Int) -> T {
        let subclass: T.Type = T.self
        var calculators = [subclass]()
        for i in 0..<num {
            calculators.append(subclass())
        }
        return calculators
    }
}

let scis: [ScientificCalculator] = ScientificCalculator.createMultiple(2)
for sci in scis {
    sci.showKind()
}
```

With that code, the line `var calculators = [subclass]()` shows the error `Invalid use of '()' to call a value of non-function type '[T.Type]'`.

How can I return an array of ScientificCalculators from `Calculator.createMultiple`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track but you've made some mistakes.

First you need to return a array of `T` and not just a single element. So you need to change the return type from `T` to `[T]`:

```
class func createMultiple<T:Calculator>(num: Int) -> [T] {
```

Also you can just use `T` to initialize new instances of your subclass like that:

```
var calculators:[T] = [T]()
```

But the other parts are correct. So you final method would look like that:

```
extension Calculator {
    class func createMultiple<T:Calculator>(num: Int) -> [T] {
        let subclass: T.Type = T.self
        var calculators = [T]()
        for i in 0..<num {
            calculators.append(subclass())
        }
        return calculators
    }
}
```

**Edit**
If you are using Swift 1.2 you don't have to deal with `subclass` anymore and you will be able to use `T` instead like shown in Airspeeds answer.

```
calculators.append(T())
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: this behaviour appears to have changed in the latest Swift 1.2 beta.  You shouldn’t need to use `T.self`.  `T` is the type you want to create. But if you are using 1.1, it appears not to work (even if `T` is the subtype, it creates the supertype), and using the metatype to create the type works around this problem.  See end of answer for a 1.1 version.

You don’t need to mess with `subclass: T.Type = T.self`.  Just use `T` – that itself is the type (or rather, a placeholder for whatever type is specified by the caller):

```
extension Calculator {
    // you meant to return an array of T, right?
    class func createMultiple<T: Calculator>(num: Int) -> [T] {
        // declare an array of T
        var calculators = [T]()
        for i in 0..<num {
            // create new T and append
            calculators.append(T())
        }
        return calculators
    }
}
```

btw, you can replace that `for` loop with map:

```
class func createMultiple<T: Calculator>(num: Int) -> [T] {
    return map(0..<num) { _ in T() }
}
```

If you are still on Swift 1.1, you need to use `T.self` to work around a problem where the subtype is not properly created:

```
extension Calculator {
    // only use this version if you need this to work in Swift 1.1:
    class func createMultiple<T: Calculator>(num: Int) -> [T] {
        let subclass: T.Type = T.self
        return map(0..<num) { _ in subclass() }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that code doesn't create  ScienceCalculator but normal Calculator objects.

Comment: @ChristianWoerz no, it creates whatever T is

Comment: If I try your code in Playground it creates a regular calculator if i call the function from the ScienceCalculator class like the OP did.

Comment: Are you specifying T appropriately?  i.e. `let scis = ScientificCalculator.createMultiple(2);for sci in scis { sci.showKind() }`.  Note, this is also how the question calls it.

Comment: I've used your method and replaced the method from the OP with yours and left everything else as it was.

Comment: Works fine for me, are you using Swift 1.2?

Comment: Interesting, just fired up non-beta Xcode and indeed you’re right, it doesn’t create the subtype, only the super type.  This seems to be a bug that is fixed in the latest beta – the `T.self` part should not be necessary.

Comment: You're right. I've used the current version and not the beta.

Comment: I marked @ChristianWoerz's answer correct since I'm using non-beta Xcode. But this answer seems like the correct answer for those using Swift 1.2.

Comment: @yndolok the problem with this is that is is only going to be correct for a few more weeks until 1.2 comes out of beta – so people will get the wrong info if they come across it at a later date and think that’s what you need to do...

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity When that happens I'll try to remember to mark your answer as accepted. For now, the other answer is correct.